# DropDownList selection behavior when using keyboard in Air/Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, keyboard, drop-down-menu

Let's say I have a DropDownList with the 50 states in it. I would like to type in the letters "**C** + **O** + **L**" to jump to Colorado, like Firefox and most application do.

Right now, it's jumping from California to Ohio to end with Louisiana... Anybody know an easy way to do that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can try my custom Flex 4 based component InputAssist to achieve the functionality that you need http://www.jabbypanda.com/blog/2010/09/flex-4-autocomplete-is-now-known-as-inputassist-announcing-0-1-release/

Comment: @JabbyPanda thanks, really like the behavior of your comp, clean and efficient, though it's not exactly what I'm looking for, I'll keep it in mind. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to create a custom component that extends the DropDownList and override the offending function to add your own functionality that you want.  It's the only way I can think of changing the default functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Like @J_A_X proposed, I modified the DropDownList class, adding a timer that keeps the string that the user is typing for ¾ seconds and then, reset it. Here's my solution :

```
package MyComps
{
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.utils.setTimeout;

import mx.core.mx_internal;

import spark.components.DropDownList;

use namespace mx_internal;

public class DropDownListKeyboardSelection extends DropDownList
{

    private var _duration:Number = 750; // Time in milliseconds before the _str is resetted
    private var _timer:Timer;
    private var _str:String = '';

    public function DropDownListKeyboardSelection()
    {
        super();
    }

    override mx_internal function findKey(eventCode:int):Boolean
    {
        if (!dataProvider || dataProvider.length == 0)
            return false;

        if (eventCode >= 33 && eventCode <= 126)
        {
            var matchingIndex:Number;
            var keyString:String = String.fromCharCode(eventCode);

            // Freshly instantiated or resetted by timerEnded(). In that case, we start the timer
            if (_str == '') {
                startTimer();
            }   else {
                _timer.reset();
                startTimer();
            }

            // Building the string to find
            _str += keyString;

            matchingIndex = findStringLoop(_str, 0, dataProvider.length); 

            // We didn't find the item, loop back to the top 
            if (matchingIndex == -1)
            {
                matchingIndex = findStringLoop(keyString, 0, 0); 
            }

            if (matchingIndex != -1)
            {
                if (isDropDownOpen)
                    changeHighlightedSelection(matchingIndex);
                else
                    setSelectedIndex(matchingIndex, true); 

                return true;
            }

        }

        return false;
    }

    // Let's start the _timer
    private function startTimer():void
    {
        _timer = new Timer(_duration);  
        _timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerEnded);
        _timer.start();
    }

    // Timer ended, let's reset the _str variable
    private function timerEnded(event:TimerEvent):void
    {   
        _str = '';
        _timer.reset();
    }

} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is dependant on the browser (if using the standard list element). You could create an autocomplete field through jquery (although this isn't the same as a drop down list).

Comment: I should have mentioned that it is in an AIR application, in Flex. Sorry  ;-)

Comment: Ah, sorry just seen your tags. I was about to suggest you use http://coffeescripter.com/code/editable-select/ - but won't be any use to you